# Change function arguments in Bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to change function arguments before passing them to a next function.

```
firstfunction() {
   # change "-f" to "--format" in arguments
   secondfunction "$@"
}
```

I tried to convert to an array, change the array and convert back to arguments. But it looks so complicated. Is it possible to make it simpler?

UPDATE: to be more specific...

```
firstfunction data.txt -f "\d+"
```

should call

```
secondfunction data.txt --format "\d+"
```

Comment: @anubhava For simplicity let's assume I need to change short options to long options: -f --> --format, -x --> --execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly tough problem. Bash is simply not very good at working with (slightly) complex data structures like arrays.

I think the only conceivable robust solution will require a loop. This is the easiest way I can think of:

```
function firstfunction {
    local -A map=(['-f']='--format');
    local -a args=();
    local arg;
    for arg in "$@"; do
        if [[ -v map[$arg] ]]; then
            args+=("${map[$arg]}");
        else
            args+=("$arg");
        fi;
    done;
    echo ${args[@]+"${args[@]}"}; ## replace echo with secondfunction to run
};
firstfunction;
##
firstfunction a b;
## a b
firstfunction x -f -fff -f-f -fxy x-f \ -f -f\  -f;
## x --format -fff -f-f -fxy x-f  -f -f  --format
```

Using `${args[@]+"${args[@]}"}` instead of just `"${args[@]}"` for the final expansion works around the ill-advised design decision the bash developers made to reject an empty array as an "unbound variable" if you have the `nounset` set option (`set -u`) enabled. See [Bash empty array expansion with `set -u`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577052/bash-empty-array-expansion-with-set-u).

---

Alternative:

```
function firstfunction {
    local -A map=(['-f']='--format');
    local -a args=("$@");
    local -i i;
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#args[@]}; ++i)); do
        if [[ -v map[${args[i]}] ]]; then
            args[i]="${map[${args[i]}]}";
        fi;
    done;
    echo ${args[@]+"${args[@]}"}; ## replace echo with secondfunction to run
};
```

Comment: Thank you @bgoldst! I was playing with @anubhava's solution and realized than I actually need more general.

Comment: Not for nitpicking but `firstfunction -fabc` is a valid option argument to send `abc` with `-f` option. To be generic it should become `--format abc` or `--format=abc`

Comment: You can use a much simpler loop here: `for arg in "$@"; do`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getopts` to reliable parse and process optional arguments like this:

```
firstfunction() {
   OPTIND=1
   local arr=()
   while getopts "f:x:" opt; do
      case $opt in
         f) arr+=("--format $OPTARG");;
         x) arr+=("--execute $OPTARG");;
      esac
   done
   echo "${arr[@]}"; # or call second function here
}

firstfunction -fabc -x foobar
--format abc --execute foobar

firstfunction -fabc -xfoobar
--format abc --execute foobar

firstfunction -f abc -xfoobar
--format abc --execute foobar
```

Comment: Yes that's correct @bgoldst. For foolproof way to handle this I would suggest a loop using `while getopts`