# Reliable version-independent (3.2 .. 4.4) way of bash empty array handling in '-u' mode

Tags: arrays, bash

While the solution suggested in [Bash empty array expansion with `set -u`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577052/bash-empty-array-expansion-with-set-u) worked great for me, turns out array handling has been changed in recently released (2016/09/16) bash 4.4 (available in Debian stretch, for example).

```
$ bash --version | head -n1
bash --version | head -n1
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Now empty arrays expansion does not emits warning

```
$ set -u
$ arr=()
$ echo "${arr[@]}"

$ # everything is fine
```

The solution proposed in related question fails with bash-4.4:

```
$ set -u
$ arr2=()
$ arr2=( ${arr2[@] + "${arr2[@]}"} 'foo' )
bash: ${arr2[@] + "$arr2[@]"}: bad substitution
```

Does anyone got suggestions on (more or less) version-independent solution without extra checks for array length or bash version ? 
I'm still on investigating latest bash changes myself

**EDIT**

As my initial question seems to be somewhat confusing, here is clarification of what I try to achieve.
Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
bash --version | head -n1

arr=()

# some external environment variables are set / command line arguments passed to script
if test -n "${USE_EXTRA_ARGUMENT_1-}" ; then
  arr=( ${arr[@] + "${arr[@]}"} 'foo' )
fi

if test -n "${USE_EXTRA_ARGUMENT_2-}" ; then
  arr=( ${arr[@] + "${arr[@]}"} 'bar' )
fi

# just a dummy command
echo "${arr[@]-}"
```

Bash 4.3 (Arch linux) run:

```
$ USE_EXTRA_ARGUMENT_1=baz bash xxx.sh 
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
foo
```

Bash 4.4 (Debian stretch) run:

```
$ USE_EXTRA_ARGUMENT_1=baz bash xxx.sh
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
xxx.sh: line 9: ${arr[@] + "${arr[@]}"}: bad substitution
```

Or I'm gravely wrong in using bash arrays ?

Comment: My honest suggestion is to use Python instead.

Comment: I do love and use Python a lot, but that's not an option sometimes

Comment: This has nothing to do with `set -u`; `${arr[@] + ...}` is just bad syntax.

Comment: For folks coming here to attempt to resolve the `set -u` error in versions of Bash prior to Bash 4.4, see my answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551944/113632).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space before `+` is wrong; you mean

```
arr2=( ${arr2[@]+"${arr2[@]}"} 'foo' )
```

It's much simpler, though, to use the `+=` operator.

```
arr2+=(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me, white spaces was last thing I could think of