# Pass options received in bash script to a called script, command or builtin

Tags: bash, getopt

I have a bash script `myscript.sh`.
I mean to call another script, command or builtin from within it, e.g., `diff`.
I mean to pass options to `myscript.sh`, some of which would be passed to `diff` when calling it.

The way I implemented this is by setting up an option string `optstring` via `getopt`, and then using

```
eval "diff ${optstring} ${file} ${TRG_DIR}/${filebase2}"
```

So far, it worked, but I do not know if this is prone to issues when passing arguments with wildcards, etc. At any rate, ...

**Is there a better way to do it?**

---

The way I set up `optstring` is

```
set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail
params="$(getopt -o qy --long brief,side-by-side,suppress-common-lines --name "$0" -- "$@")"

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then echo "Failed parsing options." >&2 ; exit 1 ; fi

echo params=$params
echo params=$@

eval set -- "$params"

optstring=""
# These variables are likely not needed
brief=false
sbs=false
scl=false

#while false ; do
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -q|--brief)
            optstring=${optstring}" -q"
            brief=true
            echo "brief"
            shift
            ;;
        -y|--side-by-side)
            optstring=${optstring}" -y"
            sbs=true
            echo "side-by-side"
            shift
            ;;
        --suppress-common-lines)
            optstring=${optstring}" --suppress-common-lines"
            scl=true
            echo "suppress-common-lines"
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Not implemented: $1" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
echo optstring=${optstring}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array. Arrays can handle multi-word arguments with whitespace. Initialize a blank array with:

```
options=()
```

To append an option, do:

```
options+=(--suppress-common-lines)
```

Then finally you can get rid of the `eval` when you call `diff` and just call it normally. Make sure to quote all of the variable expansions in case they have whitespace:

```
diff "${options[@]}" "$file" "$TRG_DIR/$filebase2"
```

Comment: I found that when there are no options, I get the error `options[@]: unbound variable`. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577052/bash-empty-array-expansion-with-set-u addresses the issue.